# Leaving phone plugged in all the time?

Tags: battery, charging, hardware

I have a spare OnePlus One that I use for home automation stuff (RM Plugin, Tasker, etc.) I leave it plugged in all the time. Sometimes the phone does get quite hot. Just today, wanting to do more Tasker stuff with it, I noticed that the screen popped out a bit, guessing due to battery swelling.

I'm basically confused what causes what between:

- Leaving the phone plugged in all the time
- App power management (like sometimes screen was left on, etc.)
- High temp
- Battery swell

Also, would it be possible to continue using the OnePlus?

Thanks!

Comment: I want to use an android phone for similar stuff too. The best solution would be to use the device with battery removed or a device that is designed to work only plugged in to electricity, which doesn't have a battery. Anyone knows about such solutions?

Comment: Saw some DIY stuff involving removing old battery terminal and connecting it to a regulated voltage supply.

Comment: I saw some of them too, but not all were successful. I wonder if there are any cheap devices that don't have a battery in the first place. They would serve well as (almost) always on wall mounted displays, or could be used in cars for example.

Answer (score 0):

You can leave the phone plugged in. Modern phones have advanced charging electronics, that should prevent overcharging and similar problems.

But when the battery is swelling, you should *not* continue using the phone. It may start to burn or explode. When you still have seller's warranty, use it. Otherwise I would still buy a new one as soon as possible. Defect batteries can be dangerous.